# change file extension for import with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I have react project with webpack-5

and inside some components folder there is 2 style type (sibling):

1. fileName.css
2. fileName.shad.css

only .css imported files inside my code like:
`import "./fileName.css";`

> and fileName.shad.css never imported

but i need 2 type of build

1. normal build use only.CSS files (which is imported)
2. shad build use only .shad.css files (not imported but present)

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"), // the bundle output path
    filename: "bundle.js", // the name of the bundle
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html", // to import index.html file inside index.js
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 3030, // you can change the port
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, // .js and .jsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // excluding the node_modules folder
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/, // styles files
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, // to import images and fonts
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: { limit: false },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I really need to replace files on build

Comment: You can have to files that import two CSS files, and then bundle with two separated entries

Comment: i cant. my project is too big !